# why is ec2 free tier being charged

Tags: amazon-ec2, rhel

I launched a t2.micro instance which at the time of launch clearly stated *free tier eligible*.

It is a RHEL7 system on which I then installed some usual software such as Java, Tomcat, nginx etc.

In the billing section, I see that I am being charged for this instance. So far I have been charged $2.36 at the rate of $0.073 for 36 hours.

How do I explain this?

Comment: Terms and Conditions are [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/terms/). How long have you had your account? Is the charge for the EC2 instance itself, or is it for EBS storage or another Amazon service? You'd need to give a bit more info (but this question is probably off-topic of SO anyway). See also the [last-but-one FAQ Question](https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free period only lasts 12 months from the time you first created your AWS account - is your account new?

Comment: No it is not. Thanks, I missed that.